# Error first run jhipster application

Tags: java, postgresql, gradle, gulp, jhipster

I try to run jhipster application. But I have error.

> Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
>   Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\bin\java.exe'' finished wi
>   th non-zero exit value 1

I have checked my PATH variable and JAVA_HOME, those are correct.  What's mean the error?
I use Gradle, Gulp, PostrgeSQL configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to say. Maybe you should to check you PostrgeSQL configuration. 
Check this file [src/main/resources/config/application-dev.yml](http://src/main/resources/config/application-dev.yml)

For PostgreSQL it should be seems like that:

```
datasource: 
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/%db-name%
    name: 
    username: ****
    password: ****
```

Same error can be if your app don't have access to database